# Como agrupar elementos dinamicamente indepente do tamanho?

Tags: css

Tenho uma `div` pai que é responsável por agrupar determinadas quantidades de filhos.

O problema é preciso que essa div fique sempre alinhada à esquerda, sem deixar espaços em branco, porém cada div pai tem um número diferente de elementos filhos.

Isso faz com que cada div pai tenha um height diferente, e, consequentemente, o `float: left` em alguns casos faz com que um elemento fique alinhado à direita, deixando um enorme espaço em branco a esquerda. Isso quando não fica um espaço em branco em cima.

Vou exemplificar o problema que tenho com duas imagens:

## Problema

[image: Os items deveriam ficar flexíveis, porém estão deixando um espaço indesejado]

[image: Os items deveriam ficar flexíveis, porém estão deixando um espaço indesejado]

## Solução desejada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tipo o site Pinterest ?

Comment: Exatamante, @DiegoSouza

Comment: Uma vez que precisei disso usei um plugin jQuery. Se for do seu interesse é esse aqui: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Masonry-style-Fluid-Image-Grid-Plugin-For-jQuery-fluid/. Talvez você já tenha pesquisado.

Answer (score -1):

tente utilizar a seguinte marcação `HTML` que deve funcionar:

```css
#conteudo {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px:
}
#barra-lateral {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 400px;:
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#conteudo .item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#barra-lateral .item {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<div id="barra-lateral">
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
```